# Angular JS Directive Definition - Require ngModelController as well as a custom controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to write my Angular directives to have most of their functionality in the code of their controllers, with the link function just being used to bind two different directive controllers together.

I'm running into a problem when it comes to both 'require'ing a controller, and having the 'controller' defined as well. How am I supposed to get a reference in the link function to the controller I've specified?

Sample code (without of course all the surrounding module.directive stuff)

```
return {
    require:'ngModel',
    controller: 'CustomDirectiveCtrl',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers)
    {
        console.log(controllers);
    }
};
```

'controllers' contains ngModelController, but doesn't give me a way to access CustomDirectiveCtrl.

How can I access both ngModelController, and CustomDirectiveCtrl, from the link function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bindToController with require in Angular Directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903887/bindtocontroller-with-require-in-angular-directive)

Comment: This question, while good, is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903887/bindtocontroller-with-require-in-angular-directive which has a very good answer already

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, this is a duplicate. I feel like the other question really could use a code snippet to explain the problem. As well, the 'bindToController' which is referenced in that question obscures the real question, which is really: 'How do I access a directive's own controller in the link function body?'

Comment: You are right, I wonder what should I do in that case, I would like to search the other question using your title (p.s. thanks for accepting the answer and improving it). Consider also that this is the only resource I found on web where someone else explores the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you never find a problem until you try explaining it to someone else.

After looking at the source for Angular JS's ngModel, I found the solution. Here's how to fix my above code, just in case anyone else is running into the same problem of understanding:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2347

```
module.directive('customDirective', function(){
    return {
          require:['customDirective', 'ngModel'],
          controller: 'CustomDirectiveCtrl',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers){
               // CustomDirectiveCtrl is controllers[0],
               // NgModelController is controllers[1]
               console.log(controllers);
          }
    }
});
```

I thought there needed to be a different syntax for getting your own controller, vs getting a different model's controller. It's simpler than I thought.