# bindToController with require in Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

If my directive uses "`require`" to use a different directive, say `ngModel`, and uses isolate scope how am I able to use the `bindToController` syntax and still be able to access the injectables (`ngModelController`) from the controller?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How would you do this without `bindToController`? All that `bindToController: true` does is it binds the isolate scope property `scope: { prop: "=" }` to the property of the controller: `this.prop`.

In both cases, the way to pass a "required" controller would be the same, which is to `require` your own controller and set its property to whatever you want, including other controllers:

```
app.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    require: ["foo", "bar"],
    controller: function(){
      this.doSomethingWithBar = function(){
        this.bar.doSomething();
      };
    },
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    bindToController: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
      var foo = ctrls[0], bar = ctrls[1];
      foo.bar = bar;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is certainly the correct answer and should be accepted.